# UIPageControl UIScrollView animated effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'd like to be able to swipe the screen to the left and right to display different user details (see link to screenshot below). I'd also like the animated effect where you see the items leave the screen on one side and the new items appear from the opposite side.

Elements used on storyboard.

- UIViewController
- UIImageView
- UILabel x 3
- UIPageControl

For starters, I don't know which elements I need to get this effect. I'm looking for someone to tell me what elements I need and sample code to go with it.

Screenshot of my ViewController - http://oi60.tinypic.com/k3roqp.jpg

I do not want to use UIPageViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled or a `UIPageViewController` to display multiple view controllers as pages. There are plenty tutorials on the web for those.

You can find documentation for those controls directly at Apples website:

- UIScrollView: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html
- UIPageViewController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html